# perl Dowload email headers from gmail for parsing

Tags: perl, email, imap

I am writing an Icinga plugin to check if the smtp server we have contracted with a third party gets blacklisted.

The service uses an unknown number of smtp relays. I need to download all the "Received" sections of the headers, and parse them to get the different IPs of the SMTP relays.

I am trying to use [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient), and I can perform some operations on the account (login, chose folder, search the messages, etc), but I haven't found a way to get the whole header nor the sections of it I need.

I don't mind using a different module if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [the `parse_headers` function](http://search.cpan.org/~plobbes/Mail-IMAPClient/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod#parse_headers).  According to the example in the documentation, you can use it like this:

```
$hashref = $imap->parse_headers(1,"Date","Received","Subject","To");
```

And then you get a hash reference that maps field names to references to array of values, like this:

```
  $hashref = {
      "Date"     => [ "Thu, 09 Sep 1999 09:49:04 -0400" ]  ,
      "Received" => [ q/
        from mailhub ([111.11.111.111]) by mailhost.bigco.com
        (Netscape Messaging Server 3.6)  with ESMTP id AAA527D for
        <bigshot@bigco.com>; Fri, 18 Jun 1999 16:29:07 +0000
        /, q/
        from directory-daemon by mailhub.bigco.com (PMDF V5.2-31 #38473)
        id <0FDJ0010174HF7@mailhub.bigco.com> for bigshot@bigco.com
        (ORCPT rfc822;big.shot@bigco.com); Fri, 18 Jun 1999 16:29:05 +0000 (GMT)
        /, q/
        from someplace ([999.9.99.99]) by smtp-relay.bigco.com (PMDF V5.2-31 #38473)
        with ESMTP id <0FDJ0000P74H0W@smtp-relay.bigco.com> for big.shot@bigco.com; Fri,
        18 Jun 1999 16:29:05 +0000 (GMT)
        /] ,
      "Subject" => [ qw/ Help! I've fallen and I can't get up!/ ] ,
      "To"      => [ "Big Shot <big.shot@bigco.com> ] ,
  };
```

That should give you all the `Received` headers in a single array.

Comment: There was an issue n how I was trying to access the message IDs, because of this I couldn't get the above snippet to work. Nonetheless that's the way to go